# Windows 10 doesn't react when I attempt to eject a disk?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, usb

I'm dealing with a problem that is making me wonder whether I should just give up and reinstall the OS. I have a Windows 10 PC that absolutely will not eject any device. No, this is not the typical, you have some program open and it gives you an error saying it's in use, this is bizarre. The OS doesn't react at all. No error, no "disk removed". It doesn't matter how many times I click this:

[image: Eject Amazon Kindle]

Disk still showed as inserted, and I can read/write to it no matter how many times I hit "eject". Shady third party utilities simply freeze and Windows asks me if I want to kill them or keep waiting.

[image: USB Disk Ejector]

If I go ahead and yank it out, it shows as "Unreadable" in disk management, yet still shows in Windows Explorer, just as an empty unwritable drive.

[image: Empty unwritable drive]

I can even still try in vain to tell Windows to eject it, Windows will just ignore me. If I try to replug it, there's seemingly nothing I can do to get Windows to mount it again. I can plug and replug it constantly and the OS won't react at all.

What is going on? Is this fixable?

Comment: Actually, after having a similar problem, (and also finding Notifications did not work, even where ejection did occur), and trying many other fixes, I found reinstallation, keeping files, did work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall the drives related to that drive from your device manager. Don't worry when you connect the drive next time it automatically reinstalls those drives related to the drive. If it doesn't fix then try creating a new user account and see whether that fixes the issue.

If either of these fixes doesn't work then you may have to reinstall windows. Additionally, you can also try using some system care software and clean the system.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and quite possibly not the same issue as you, but I solved it this way;
I could see that my sdCard (in my case) were still being accessed so I used Windows Resource Monitor (from Task Manager) to see who was accessing the card.
In my case it was my AntiVirus, which I disabled in order to be able to eject the card/disk. I can only suggest that you try to find what program/process that could possibly lock the disk - perhaps initially using a 'sledgehammer' approach - perhaps even killing off stuff until you are able to release. Then you may be knowledgeable enough to 'be nicer' in later scenarios.